# What's wrong with the code for this beginner javascript math problem?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to code a solution to the following problem and am running into some difficulty:

If we list all the natural numbers below 10 that are multiples of 3 or 5, we get 3, 5, 6 and 9. The sum of these multiples is 23.

Finish the solution so that it returns the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below the number passed in.

Note: If the number is a multiple of both 3 and 5, only count it once.

Here's the code that I have:

```
function solution(number){
  var sum = 0,
  for (i = 0, i < number, i++) {
  if ((i % 3 === 0) && (i % 5 === 0)) {
  sum += i }
  else if  ((i % 3 === 0) || (i % 5 === 0)) {
  sum += i }
  }
  return sum;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try the code in the answer?

Answer (score 1):

You only need a single test: if `i % 3 === 0 || i % 5 === 0` is satisfied, then add `i` to `sum`.

Make sure not to implicitly create global variables; `i = 0` will throw an error in strict mode. Always declare variables when using them for the first time.

```js
function solution(number) {
  var sum = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < number; i++) {
    if (i % 3 === 0 || i % 5 === 0) {
      sum += i;
    }
  }
  return sum;
}

console.log(solution(10));
```

You also need to put semicolons in the `for` loop declaration, not commas.